# Multiple table in a same Row using Python-docx?

Tags: django, python-docx

I want to create two separate tables starting at the same line.
I already tried WD_TABLE_DIRECTION, WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT it works only for a different line or a level different line.

```
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_DIRECTION

table = document.add_table(3, 3)

table.direction = WD_TABLE_DIRECTION.RTL or  table.direction = WD_TABLE_DIRECTION.LTR
```

---

```
from docx.enum.table import WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT

table = document.add_table(3, 3)

table.alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER or LEFT or RIGHT
```

Answer (score 0):

A table is a block-level item, like a paragraph, and so cannot directly appear side-by-side with another table or paragraph. A block-level item consumes all the space between the margins of the page or column, and block items form a "stack" vertically going down the page.

However, a table can appear *inside a cell* of another table. So you can create a one-row, two-column table and place a table in each of its two cells. This would result in them appearing to be "on the same line".